# Can gzip compress application/octet-stream

Tags: webserver, compression, gzip

Particularly in web, is it possible to compress application/octet-steam, I am serving video files from AWS to a web app and data transfer is very expensive at high scale

Answer (score 2):

`gzip` will attempt to compress anything it’s given, regardless of the MIME type; so you can feed it `application/octet-stream`-identified data. However video files are already compressed, and `gzip` won’t be able to compress them further.

The only way to reduce the size of video files is to re-encode them in a lower resolution and/or lower bitrate and/or with a more efficient codec.

Comment: or using a better codec than motion jpeg

Comment: I've already adopted AV1, 50% better than h264, but with S3 insane data transfer billing (.09\GB) my bill reaches $2.7K monthly for 30TB of transfer, I am thinking seriously to switch to a local minio server